# dynamic adjustment of the environment in DataTemplates through (Visible/Invisible)-property

Tags: datatemplate, maui

The problem is that if you include a DataTemplate from ContentPage.Resources from CollectionView with ItemTemplate and make fields visible or invisible in it, then the environment does not adapt to this change.

I've created a short example below.
You have a button and under the button a label, which has set IsVisible=false as default and the button sets it to true.
Now you can see that the label field in the DataTemplate is not properly indented.

a visual Example of the problem
[visual representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hb8Mx.png)

Many thanks and best regards Marcel

The Code for the Example (MainPage and Person.cs)

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Example.MainPage" 
             x:DataType="local:MainPage"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Example"
             x:Name="ContentPage"
             >
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <DataTemplate  x:Key="SideBySide"  x:DataType="local:Person"  >
            <VerticalStackLayout >
                <Button Text="Show Label" TextColor="Black" Clicked="Button_Clicked" FontSize="20" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"  BackgroundColor="Red" IsVisible="{Binding Path=BindingContext.Visible, Source={x:Reference ContentPage}}"/>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>

    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ScrollView>
        <CollectionView    ItemsSource="{Binding Personen}"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource  Key=SideBySide}" />
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Example;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }

    private bool _visible = false;
    public bool Visible { get { return _visible; } set { _visible = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }

    public ObservableCollection<Person> Personen { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Person>() 
                                                                { new Person(1, "Person1"),new Person(2, "Person2") ,new Person(3, "Person3")  };

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Visible= !Visible;
    }
}
```

Person.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;


namespace Example
{
    public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _id;
        private string _name;

        public Person(int _id, string _name)
        {
            Id = _id;
            Name = _name;
        }
        public int Id { get { return _id; } set { _id = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
        public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried it with several different layouts and they all have the same problem.
Also with e.g. TableView and
viewCell.ForceUpdateSize(); i couldn't fix it.

Comment: Have you tried all possibilities to redraw it? Invalidates, etc?

Comment: sry, I'm still a beginner, I worked with the Maui documentation and tried to adjust it with "Binding Value Converter", "Events" or directly the property (like height ).
If you could send me a link with the possible ways to fix the problem it would help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```cs
var holdP = Personen;
Personen = null;
Personen = holdP;
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Personen));
```

If that works, then try variations to see which statements can be eliminated.

An alternative to setting to null then back, is to set Personen to a new ObservableCollection, holding the same elements.